# how to run a specific function with several ID's

Tags: jquery, document

I have a php page that includes 5 php files. in each of the files, I put an input[button] for each php file, when the user click on it, the function will be fired.
As I'm not allowed to use same ID in the page, I'm getting confused to apply     $(document).ready(function(){..}) for each ID. How can I handle it?
More clearly:
I have ('#add_more1,#add_more2,#add_more3,#add_more4,#add_more5). What I want is when the user click on each of those ID's, it fires the code below.
for example if he click on ('#add_more2') , it will run the code
thank's in advanced.

```
 //  To add new input file field dynamically, on click of "Add More Files" button below function will be executed.
$('#add_more2').click(function() {
    $('#show2').append($("<div/>", {
        id: 'filediv'
    }).fadeIn('slow').append($("<input/>", {
        name: 'file[]',
        type: 'file',
        id: 'file'
    })));
});
// Following function will executes on change event of file input to select different file.
$('body').on('change', '#file', function() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        counter += 1; // Incrementing global variable by 1. 
        $(this).before("<div id='abcd" + counter + "' class='abcd'><img id='previewimg" + counter + "' src=''/></div>");
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        $(this).hide();
        $("#abcd" + counter).append($("<i/>", {
            id: 'img',
            top:0,
            class: 'fa fa-times',
            alt: 'delete'
        }).click(function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        }));
    }
});
// To Preview Image
function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    $('#previewimg' + counter).attr('src', e.target.result);
};
$('#upload').click(function(e) {
    var name = $(":file").val();
    if (!name) {
        alert("First Image Must Be Selected");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Should each element having `id` beginning with `#add_more` 1-5 clicked append `div` to `#show2` ? Or are there also elements having `id` beginning with  `#show` 1-5 corresponding to `#add_more` 1-5 ?

Comment: there are also having id beginning with #show1,show2,... ,#show5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attribute begins with selector, `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/\D/g` to replace part of `id` that is not a digit, retrieve number portion of element `id` to select corresponding element having `id` beginning with `#show`.

```js
    $("[id^=add_more]").click(function() {
        $("#show" + this.id.replace(/\D/g, "")).append($("<div/>", {
            id: "filediv"
        }).fadeIn("slow").append($("<input/>", {
            name: "file[]",
            type: "file",
            id: "file"
        })));
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="add_more1">
  add_more1
  </div>
<div id="add_more2">
  add_more2
  </div>
<div id="add_more3">
  add_more3
  </div>
<div id="add_more4">
  add_more4
  </div>
<div id="add_more5">
  add_more5
  </div>

<div id="show1">
  show1
  </div>
<div id="show2">
  show2
  </div>
<div id="show3">
  show3
  </div>
<div id="show4">
  show4
  </div>
<div id="show5">
  show5
  </div>
```

Comment: @guest271214. more clearly: I have 5 different id's like add_more1, add_more2,....,add_more5 and also have 5 different id's to show images inside this div like show1,show2,...,show5.  what I want is when the user click on add_more1, it appends into show1, if click on add_more2, it appends into show2, and so on. notice: all id's are inside on php file. How can I handle it?

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion if is that you used a same class for each button instead of id

```
$("body").on("click",".parentClass .currentClass",function() {
    $("#show2").append($("<div/>", {
        id: "filediv"
    }).fadeIn("slow").append($("<input/>", {
        name: "file[]",
        type: "file",
        id: "file"
    }));
 });
```